# Swift convert Integer to Int

Tags: swift

I am doing generics programming and have something that conforms to [Integer](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/protocol/Integer/). Somehow I need to get that into a concrete [Int](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/Int/) that I can use.

```
extension CountableRange
{
    // Extend each bound away from midpoint by `factor`, a portion of the distance from begin to end
    func extended(factor: CGFloat) -> CountableRange<Bound> {
        let theCount = Int(count) // or lowerBound.distance(to: upperBound)
        let amountToMove = Int(CGFloat(theCount) * factor)
        return lowerBound - amountToMove ..< upperBound + amountToMove
    }
}
```

The error here is on `let theCount = Int(count)`. Which states:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(Bound.Stride)'

First the error could be more helpful because `CountableRange` defines its `Bound.Stride` as [`SignedInteger`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/protocol/SignedInteger/) ([source](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/CountableRange/)). So the error could have told me that.

So I know it is an `Integer`, but how do I actually make use of the `Integer` value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numericCast()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1641576-numericcast)
to convert between different integer types. As the documentation
states:

> Typically used to do conversion to any contextually-deduced integer type.

In your case:

```
extension CountableRange where Bound: Strideable {

    // Extend each bound away from midpoint by `factor`, a portion of the distance from begin to end
    func extended(factor: CGFloat) -> CountableRange<Bound> {
        let theCount: Int = numericCast(count)
        let amountToMove: Bound.Stride = numericCast(Int(CGFloat(theCount) * factor))
        return lowerBound - amountToMove ..< upperBound + amountToMove
    }
}
```

The restriction `Bound: Strideable` is necessary to make the arithmetic
`lowerBound - amountToMove` and `upperBound + amountToMove` compile.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you starting from swift 3.0

```
let theCount:Int32 = Int32(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need that `Int`, try this instead:

```
let theCount = Int(count.toIntMax())
```

The `toIntMax()` method return this integer using Swift’s *widest* native signed integer type (i.e., `Int64` on 64-bits platforms).